# make element be of type interface A OR interface B

Tags: typescript

How can I have a variable be of type interface `A` **OR** interface `B`?

```
interface A {
  foo: string
}

interface B {
  bar: string
}

const myVar: A | B = {bar: 'value'} // tells me myVar is missing property foo.
```

How can I have `myVar` be either interface `A` or interface `B`?

Comment: who is telling you that `myVar` is missing property `foo`? is it typescript compiler which you run from console? Is it your IDE? Could you please provide a little bit more information? Also please include the contents of `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: That should work, and does in the playground/ http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myVar%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%3D%20%7Bbar%3A%20'value'%7D%20

Answer (score 0):

Just use interfaces identifiers `A` and `B` instead of `interfaceA` and `interfaceB`:

```
interface A {
  foo: string
}

interface B {
  bar: string
}

const myVar: A|B = {bar: 'value'};
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. Like I said the | sign makes me have to define the fields of A AND B

Comment: @Lev please include the contents of `tsconfig.json` to the question.